# How to configure SSL for XAMPP on macOS? Using Tildus

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, xampp

I've never settled a self-signed SSL on my XAMPP dev machine...have always used hacky workarounds (like approving a non-secure site).

Was having another go at it following these nicely laid out instructions:
https://tidus.dev/xampp-https-ssl-localhost

Followed instructions exactly...but still get (Chrome Version 99.0.4844.83 (Official Build) (arm64)) the following after visiting https://localhost/:

This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

If I remove the 's' (http://localhost/) I can visit my site.

Not sure if the problem lies with Tildus' approach to SSL in XAMPP/macOS or Chrome itself. Guidance/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this process works for me with one exception: Step 3, that calls for removing a lot of code from httpd-ssl.conf, was not the right move for me.

I simply edited 2 lines in the code to point to my newly created files, then restarted Apache, and everything was golden. Here are the two original lines (commented out) with my updates:

```
# SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl.crt/server.crt"
# Added March 2022
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/localhost.crt"

# SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl.key/server.key"
# Added March 2022
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/localhost.key"
```